# Ubuntu : panels on the wrong screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I just updated my Ubuntu from 9.04 to 9.10. Since then everything looks fine, but the panels (the one at the top with menus and date, and the one at the bottom with the running applications and the virtual desktops).
I have a dual screen, and the panels show on the wrong one... I already changed the display setting, trying to inverse the screens, but the panel always remain on the wrong screen. :'(
Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier: Alt + click and drag the panels to the other screen.

Comment: You're welcome. Seems to happen to me every time I switch distributions. I retain my old home dir, but panels move about when logging into the new systems (also, switching between 1, 2 and 3 monitors also reorganizes the panels) so it's nice to know how to cleanup easily.

Answer (score 0):

By default, panels are shown on whichever monitor is set as the primary monitor. Depending on your card, there are different ways to switch.

For NVIDIA cards, you should be able to do this with twinview or the nvidia-settings program:

[image]

Comment: Not bad, but I didn't find twinview nor nvidia-settings. Looks like it's ATI.

Comment: Run lspci to determine your card. I don't think these are installed by default regardless.

Comment: Ok, confirmed :
VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 [Radeon X1200 Series]

Comment: you're after catalyst then: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI